# Open source performance testing tool of native app

Tags: performance, testing, performance-testing

How to perform the performance testing for Iphone/Ipad application? I have loadrunner 11.0 can you please any one help for me?. Note. it is not a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to modify the source code of your testing tool to match the protocol and architecture of your application?  If so, then you can pick any open source tool as a starting point.

(It should be noted that LoadRunner v11 has a track record of being able to performance test servers using the requests of native mobile applications.)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get your question correctly here, the subject of this thread says "open source perf testing tool for native app", in the details you mention loadrunner 11. Load runner 11 has support for native applications / programs written in C.

What is that you plan to do in performance testing? Improve the response time of your programs' core logic or are you planning to do a load test your server that handles requests from your App? or Improve the Performance of your install/upgrade procedures? The list goes on...

Do you have automated tests written down for your app? To the best of my knowledge there is no open source performance test tool for native ios apps. Yet there are quite a few automation tools which can be leveraged and tweaked to measure performance testing metrics. From the back of my head I can think about Frank, Calablash, NativeDriver to test native iOS apps in an automated way.

Comment: Thanks Balaji. I am to try begin with Calabash as automated tool a few days before. Can share me some experience with it, aren't you?